# Replace Android handler with RXJava

Tags: android, handler, rx-java

In Activity I have some kind of timeout for user action. If user do nothing I need produce some other action for system.
For this I am using Handler

```
protected void stopTimeout()
{
    handler.removeMessages(0);
}

private void startTimeout()
{
    stopTimeout();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            //SOME ACTIONS
        }
    }, 180 * 1000L);
}
```

Handler can be stopped for some user actions like buttons click

```
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            // user actions
            stopTimeout();
        }
    });
```

But at the moment I have to many variants of user actions. All this push to stopTimout from async threads and handler doesn't look as proper decision.
Project I am already migrating to RXJava and

I can figure out how to done this part with RXJava.

Comment: Consider using `removeMessagesAndCallbacks(null)` for clearing the Handler.

Comment: callbacks hell, no thx, just removed all of this from project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start timer.

```
private void startTimeout() {
    stopTimeout();

    Observable<Long> observable = Observable
            .timer(getKeepMyOrderOnDisplayTime(),
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.computation());
    cancelOrderSubscription = observable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(new Func1<Long, MyOrderStorageItem>() {
                @Override
                public MyOrderStorageItem call(Long aLong) {
                    return myOrderStorageItem;
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Action1<MyOrderStorageItem>() {
                @Override
                public void call(final MyOrderStorageItem myOrderStorageItem) {
                    // SOME ACTION with object, I need
                }
            });
}
```

Stop timer.

```
protected void stopTimeout() {
    if (cancelOrderSubscription != null) {
        cancelOrderSubscription.unsubscribe();
        cancelOrderSubscription = null;
    }
}
```

On user actions add stop timer run. If no user actions while timer, default action will.

Answer (score 2):

Its simple:

```
subscription = Observable.timer(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(aLong -> whatToDo());

private void whatToDo() {
   System.out.println("Called after 1 second");
}
```